# Which tools to use and how to find file descriptors leaking from Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish, file-descriptor

We release new code to production every week and Glassfish hasn't had any problems.  This weekend we had to move racks at our hosting provider.  There were not any code changes (they just powered off, moved, re-racked and powered on) but we're on a new network infrastructure and suddenly we're leaking file descriptors like a sieve.  So I'm guessing there is some sort of connection attempting to be made which now fails due to a network change.

I'm running Glassfish v2ur2-b04/AS9.1_02 on RHEL4 with an embedded IMQ instance.  After the move I started seeing:

> [#|2010-04-25T05:34:02.783+0000|SEVERE|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web|_ThreadID=33;_ThreadName=SelectorThread-?4848;_RequestID=c4de6f6d-c1d6-416d-ac6e-49750b1a36ff;|WEB0756: Caught exception during HTTP processing.
>   java.io.IOException: Too many open files
>   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
>   ...
>   [#|2010-04-25T05:34:03.327+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver9.1|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=34;_ThreadName=Timer-1;_RequestID=d27e1b94-d359-4d90-a6e3-c7ec49a0f383;|java.lang.NullPointerException        at
>   com.sun.jbi.management.system.AutoAdminTask.pollAutoDirectory(AutoAdminTask.java:1031)

Using lsof I check the number of file descriptors and I see quite a few entries which look like:

> java    18510 root 8556u  sock                0,4           1555182 can't identify protocol
>   java    18510 root 8557u  sock                0,4           1555320 can't identify protocol
>   java    18510 root 8558u  sock                0,4           1555736 can't identify protocol
>   java    18510 root 8559u  sock                0,4           1555883 can't identify protocol

If I do a count of open file descriptors every minute I see it growing by 12 every minute.  I have no idea what these sockets are.

I've undeployed my application so there is only a plain Glassfish instance running and I still see it leaking 12 file descriptors a minute.  So I think this leak is in Glassfish or potentially IMQ.

What approach should I take to tracking down these sockets of unknown protocol?  What tools can I use (or flags can I pass to lsof) to get more information about where to look?

thanks,

chuck

Comment: It's been almost a month and still no answers. Did you ever sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution;

> assuming GlassFish runs as user
>   "glassfish"
>
> Add the following lines to
>   /etc/security/limits.conf to increase
>   the  maximum number of open files for
>   the user that Glassfish runs as:
>
> glassfish soft nofile 32768
>   glassfish hard nofile 65536